# How to query domain in jaspersoft with Dynamic Parameters

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to jaspersoft reporting. I am currently designing and developing reports by considering following requirements.
I want to create template based reports where all dynamic parameters I need to pass in SQL query.
I was going through japsersoft reporting I found that we can create join views and cache data by creating domains. So that it reduces hits at db level.

While creating report I found that I cant execute SQL script on Domain objects.

Please advice whether I am on right track or not.
Basically I want to query on cached data such as domain view instead of hitting DB directly.

Please suggest if any workaround is available for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note, although *JasperReports Server* manages a cache for *Ad Hoc Views* and *Ad Hoc Reports* running on Domains, running a JRXML report (e.g. designed in Jaspersoft Studio) on a Domain does not guarantee hitting that cache.

You also have the option of using a layer that provides caching between JasperReports Server and your database. For example, support has been recently added for TIBCO Data Virtualization (not a free product) in v.7, see https://www.jaspersoft.com/introducing-jaspersoft-7.

In any case, Domains are not relational databases and therefore do not support straight SQL.
You can use the "Domain query language" though, which offers a subset of the features of SQL. The easiest way to write a query is using Jaspersoft Studio and selecting "domain" in the *Language* dropdown (top-left corner of the *Dataset and Query Dialog*, indicated by the red arrow in the screenshot below from Studio 6.4.0):

[image: Screenshot of Dataset and Query Dialog in Jaspersoft Studio]

For example the design above (which uses the Supermart Domain, provided with the sample data) will generate this query and the required "dynamic" parameter as you requested – in this case a Collection as the filter is 'Is One Of' which can take multiple values:

```
<query>
    <queryFields>
        <queryField id="sales_fact_ALL.sales__product.sales__product__product_name"/>
        <queryField id="sales_fact_ALL.sales_fact_ALL__store_sales_2013"/>
    </queryFields>
    <queryFilterString>sales_fact_ALL.sales__store.sales__store__region.sales__store__region__sales_country in sales__store__region__sales_country_0</queryFilterString>
</query>
```

See here for another example of a query (current version of docs based on 7.1.0 release), in this case for use with the REST API: https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-rest-api-reference/v710/queryexecutor-service

The `queryFilterString` tag follows the DomEL syntax as documented here (also for 7.1.0): https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-user-guide/v71/domel-syntax